# Possible bug: duplicate questions posted

Tags: bug, status-completed

A couple times today I have seen the exact duplicate question posted on SO, one right after the other.  One example is this set: [1224217](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224218/where-does-the-sqlite-database-for-iphone-is-stored-with-the-application) and [1224218](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224217/where-does-the-sqlite-database-for-iphone-is-stored-with-the-application). Another was [this(1223322)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223322/is-it-possible-to-suppress-compiler-warnings-for-specific-tasks) and its pair, which has been deleted.  Is this possibly a bug or is there a reasonable explanation for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We accidentally removed the javascript double-click prevention on the submit button. That is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks.  I will put a lonely tick in the 'not going crazy' column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still seeing this behavior as of 8/31/2009.  Double posts seem frequent for both question responses and comments.